# Firestore query error: Object are not valid as a react child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to do a query from firestore: i want to take all the fields from collection Missions that have the same ID of the field into Clients/1/Missions (below the firestore and the code for the query).

I've tryed to do that but i have this error:

*Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with key {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead*

Here my code:

```
const GoalScreen = async (props) => {
  IDUserNum = 1;
  IDUser = IDUserNum.toString();
  if (IDUser) {
    const array = [];
    const a = await firebase.firestore().collection('Clients').doc(IDUser).collection('Missions').get();
    if(!a) {
      return(
        <View><Text>ciao</Text></View>
      )
    }
    a.forEach((IDMission) => {
      const b = a.doc(IDMission).get().ID_Mission;
      const c = firebase.firestore().doc(b).data();
      array.push[c];
      console.log(c);
    })
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
  
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>Here the should be the goals</Text>
  
        </View>
      );
  } 
  return (
    <View><Text>orso</Text></View>
  )
}
```

Here fields of Firestore

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think this error is not due to firebase. The error says that react can't render an object because it only accepts JSX Elements. Could you show us where do you use the data retrieved from firebase? Also, could you console.log it? That way we could see where in React the error occurs and if you receive the data correctly.

Comment: I don't use them yet, i just wanted to do some tests. Anyway i updated the question with the full code of the function and the screen of the error

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what query you want to do. To understand better, can you explain in other words?

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok, with the extra data I can help a little better. The problem is that you're using forEach, it doesn't return anything and so the component doesn't receive anything to render. Try using *.map* and you should at least solve this first error.

Comment: I tryed to do that but still doesn't work:

a.map((IDMission) => {
      const b = a.doc(IDMission).get().ID_Mission;
      const c = firebase.firestore().doc(b).data();
      array.push[c];
      console.log(c);
    })